# Artificially Limit C/C++ Memory Usage

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

Is there any way to easily limit a C/C++ application to a specified amount of memory (30 mb or so)? Eg: if my application tries to complete load a 50mb file into memory it will die/print a message and quit/etc.

Admittedly I can just constantly check the memory usage for the application, but it would be a bit easier if it would just die with an error if I went above.

Any ideas?

Platform isn't a big issue, windows/linux/whatever compiler.

Comment: Why not just check the size of the file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the manual page for `ulimit` on unix systems. There is a shell builtin you can invoke *before* launching your executable or (in section 3 of the manual) an API call of the same name.

Comment: Note that the `ulimit()` API is obsolete. You want `setrlimit()` instead.

Comment: @bstpierre: The man page on my Mac OS 10.5 box doesn't mention anything about that (though `setrlimit (2)` is also present and postdates `ulimit (3)`). Do you know what standards make the change?

Comment: Man page on my linux box says: `CONFORMING TO SVr4, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 marks ulimit() as obsolete.` See the note on the [online man page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ulimit.html#tag_16_630_13).

Comment: rlimit cannot limit RSS since forever. "See Specifies the limit (in pages) of the process's resident set (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM). This limit only has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30, and there only affects calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED. "

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak Time marches on, it seems. If you have the time an up-to-date post here (or a link to one elsewhere on the site) does more good than just leaving a comment.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, you can't set a quota for memory usage of a process directly. You can, however, create a Windows job object, set the quota for the job object, and then assign the process to that job object.

Answer (score 5):

Override all malloc APIs, and provide handlers for new/delete, so that you can book keep the memory usage and throw exceptions when needed.

Not sure if this is even easier/effort-saving than just do memory monitoring through OS-provided APIs.

Comment: I would do that :) (it's enough to hook the HeapAlloc() win32 API)

Answer (score 5):

In bash, use the [ulimit builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-ulimit-147):

```
bash$ ulimit -v 30000
bash$ ./my_program
```

The -v takes 1K blocks.

**Update:**

If you want to set this from within your app, use [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit). Note that the man page for `ulimit(3)` explicitly says that it is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the size of the virtual memory of your process using the system limits.  If you process exceeds this amount, it will be killed with a signal (SIGBUS I think).

You can use something like:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class RLimit {
public:
    RLimit(int cmd) : mCmd(cmd) {
    }

    void set(rlim_t value) {
        clog << "Setting " << mCmd << " to " << value << endl;
        struct rlimit rlim;
        rlim.rlim_cur = value;
        rlim.rlim_max = value;
        int ret = setrlimit(mCmd, &rlim);
        if (ret) {
            clog << "Error setting rlimit" << endl;
        }
    }

    rlim_t getCurrent() {
        struct rlimit rlim = {0, 0};
        if (getrlimit(mCmd, &rlim)) {
            clog << "Error in getrlimit" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return rlim.rlim_cur;
    }
    rlim_t getMax() {
        struct rlimit rlim = {0, 0};
        if (getrlimit(mCmd, &rlim)) {
            clog << "Error in getrlimit" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        return rlim.rlim_max;
    }

private:
    int mCmd;
};
```

And then use it like that:

```
RLimit dataLimit(RLIMIT_DATA);
dataLimit.set(128 * 1024 );  // in kB
clog << "soft: " << dataLimit.getCurrent() << " hard: " << dataLimit.getMax() << endl;
```

This implementation seems a bit verbose but it lets you easily and cleanly set different limits (see `ulimit -a`).